# flex: referencing calling object from popUp

Tags: apache-flex, popup

I have a situation where I have some images on screen with business properties(value, quantity, qualitygrade) assigned to them. When I click on them, a popUp window needs to open and allow me to change properties for the item under the image. How do I reference 
a) object that caused the popup to open
b) properties of the object that are housed in a array- both for initial view and change

I have the images enabled for doubleclick as follows

```
newImage.doubleClickEnabled=true;
newImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK,createModifyPopUp);
```

I am currently calling the popUp window as follows

```
private function createModifyPopUp(evt:MouseEvent):void{
var mywin1:Modify=PopUpManager.createPopUp(this,Modify,true) as Modify;
PopUpManager.centerPopUp(mywin1);
}
```

I don't seem to be passing an event into the popup- Is there a way I can work based on the image clicked in the original application to build and capture information in the modify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simply use *PopUpManager.addPopup* instead of *PopUpManager.createPopUp*

your example should look like this:

```
//define properties in the Modify class (Modify.as3 or Modify.mxml)
public var someData: Array;
public var eventTarget: Object;


// listener
private function createModifyPopUp(evt:MouseEvent):void{
   var modify: Modify = new Modify();
   // pass parameters to the instance of Modify class
   modify.someData = arr;
   modify.eventTarget = evt.target;

   // show popup
   PopUpManager.addPopUp(modify, this, true);
   PopUpManager.centerPopUp(modify);
}
```

Comment: Thanks aav- just to understand this better. If I have an array called 'arr' that contains the properties, I understand I should set modify.somedata to arr; and in the 'modify' mxml class I will change values to somedata. Also, evt.currentTarget will work in the modify class. Is this correct?

Comment: 1. of course you should define someData property in the Modify class

2. evt.currentTarget will not be visible from the Modify class, unless you will pass it there. 

I updated my answer with bette

Comment: Hi: looks like the popup object isnt getting created

Comment: Hi: looks like the popup object isn't getting created: On running and initiating the createModifyPopUp, get a runtime error          Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at mx.managers::PopUpManagerImpl/centerPopUp()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\PopUpManagerImpl.as:491]
 at mx.managers::PopUpManager$/centerPopUp()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\PopUpManager.as:213]
at<line corrp to PopUpManager.centerPopUp(mywin1)>
- mywin1 not getting created- this come up with addPopUp vs create-any idea why?

Comment: popup is created by your code (... = new Modify(); ). i think that the problem is that addPopUp does not return anything (my fault in the initial example). but this not needed, since you have a reference on the popup. take a look at the updated example.

Comment: Thanks- this worked; thought had some difficulty in figuring out I had used a mx titlewindow instead of spark and it would just hang w/o any alerts!! Sorry- but 2 new questions. (a) the event object isn't registering-> how do I capture the id of the "eventTarget" in the popup for processing (b) how do I send back updated someData to the calling function... again, fully appreciate your help and expertise. Am really learning a lot today, with your inputs

Comment: i don't really get why do you need event target in your popup. if you want to inform your calling function about something happening in the popup - you can dispatch an event from your popup. define your own event by subclassing Event and defining event type constants. when it's done - your calling side can use addEventListener to attach a listener, and popup can send an event by calling dispatchEvent. find some tutorial on how to define and dispatch custom events.